# Entendendo diretiva #line

Tags: c#, terminologia, diretivas-de-compilação

Estou tentando entender a diretiva `#line`. Dei uma lida [nessa documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34dk387t.aspx) e consegui entender a aplicabilidade de `#line hidden` mas não a de `#line [any_numer].`

Tomando como exemplo um arquivo `App.g.i.cs` o que está fazendo o seguinte trecho de código no método `InitializeComponent()`:

```
#line 5 "..\..\App.xaml"
this.Startup += new System.Windows.StartupEventHandler(this.Application_Start);

#line default
#line hidden
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Está dizendo que o código `this.Startup += new System.Windows.StartupEventHandler(this.Application_Start);` vai aparecer como estando na linha 5 no arquivo `..\..\App.xaml`, não importa em que linha realmente esteja no arquivo, ou em que arquivo. Depois volta para a numeração normal.

Qualquer erro ou aviso que o compilador emita terá essa informação. No momento de depurar o código mostrará isso também.

Seu uso é bem raro e quase sempre vinculado à geradores de código. Isso normalmente é necessário quando o código é produzido por algum gerador e não escrito pelo programador. Ele pode conter algumas coisas que precisam ser mostradas para o programador de forma diferente do que é apresentado realmente, até mesmo escondidas. Sem isso algumas informações ficariam estranhas ou enganosas.

Também é usado em meta-programação, algo que é pouco incentivado, ainda, em C# (tende a ser mais usado, é o futuro da programação para algumas coisas). Mas é um tópico bem mais avançado. O motivo de não ser *mainstream* é que poucos programadores conseguem fazer certo. Como esse paradigma costuma gerar muito código é um meio de informar um número de linha que faça sentido para o programador que só costuma ver o código escrito e não o gerado, que obviamente muda a numeração das linhas.

Quase ninguém precisa saber disto, mas é um recurso útil para os casos citados.

Comment: A grosso modo está dizendo ao compilador para considerar que uma determinada linha tem tal código, mesmo que fisicamente ele não esteja lá, ou seja, "- Compile considerando que na linha `X` exista o código `Z`". Seria isso?
Interessante, eu uso meta-programação em `Python` para fazer validação de dados, é um dos truques que Python tem para se livrar dos `getters` e `setters`, mas obviamente por python ser dinâmico é muito mais fácil lidar com meta-programação.

Comment: Mais ou menos isso. Tem várias formas de usar. O normal é o compilador contar as linhas de acordo com o arquivo texto, usando esse recurso você diz que linha quer que o compilador considere ali. Dá pra fazer bastante estrago com isso. Claro que o número para efeito de compilação não muda nada, mas como informação para você muda muito. Meta-programação em linguagem estática é bem mais complicada, em uma linguagem extensiva como C#, pior ainda.